# Как получить параметр sessionid

Tags: python, requests, сессия

Нужно получить параметр sessionid из файлов cookies

Следующий код возвращает только токен:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/sportsru/')

for cookie in response.cookies:
    print('cookie domain = ' + cookie.domain)
    print('cookie name = ' + cookie.name)
    print('cookie value = ' + cookie.value)
    print('*************************************')
```

Если смотреть через f12, то я могу вручную найти этот параметр, но не понимаю, как это сделать через питон

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей вероятности в браузере вы авторизованы. Если разлогинеться, то можно увидеть, что *sessionid* не содержится куках.

Для реализации вашей задачи могу порекомендовать ознакомится с материалом: https://github.com/adarshpunj/Instagram/

Comment: Или используйте сессию requests.Session()

Comment: @СергейШашко, я пыталась, но тоже не выводит ничего. может я неправильно что-то делаю, может пожалуйста, показать пример. вот мое решение: with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get(r'https://www.instagram.com/sportsru/').json()
    print(r)

Comment: попробуйте для начала зайти на https://www.instagram.com. Если вдруг вы не авторизированны, авторизуйтесь. Все эти действия дожны быть в одной сессий.

Comment: я авторизована там

Comment: Я рад за вас. Но увы вы меня не поняли. Зайдем другой стороны, заходя  на instagram.com через  requests они вас не знают, Нужна авторизация через requests, все запросы и последушие запросы в рамках одной сессий